# Doubts & Troubles with this complex equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, real-numbers

I need to solve the following:

$$i \sin(x) + x^2 - 2x + i\cos(x) = i$$

So I tried to separate into real and imaginary part, getting

$$\begin{cases}
x^2 - 2x = 0 \\
i\sin(x) + i\cos(x) = i
\end{cases}
$$

First equation has solutions $x = 0$ and $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$, whilst the second is solved for $x = 2\pi$ or $x = \pi/2$, plus peridicity.

Now I got stuck, because I wanted to check the result, but Mathematica says it cannot solve this (neither with Solve, nor with Reduce).

$x = 0$ satisfies the whole equation, so it's a solution right?

Comment: $\sin(x) +\cos(x) = 1$ does NOT hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, I assume you thought of $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Is $x$ assumed to be real?  You didn't say so.  Also, $x^2-2x=0$ does not have $\pm\sqrt{2}$ as solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only solving over the real numbers, then you were on the right track but with a few minor errors.

The solutions to the real part, $x^2 - 2x = 0$, are $x = 0, 2$ (not $\sqrt{2}$).

The imaginary part can be rewritten as $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} \cos(x - \frac{\pi}{4}) = 1$, which has solutions for $x = 2n\pi, 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$.

As you have noticed, the solutions line up only when $x = 0$.

If you were solving over the complex numbers, then the real and imaginary parts don't separately so nicely - you can rewrite the trigonometric functions in exponential forms, but you will wind up with an expression that mixes polynomials and exponentials, which generally can only be solved in terms of the Lambert W function, and that's probably overkill depending on what you're trying to do here.